# Dealing with survival analysis data - reliability

Tags: survival, reliability

I am totally new on Survival Analysis and my data is tricking me. I have, in excel, a list of failure's records informing date and hour of ocurrence, what failed/broke on that equipment and the cause of failure.
I need to analyse that particular equipment alone and the trick thing is that all the examples and video lessons I saw use more than one item ( for example, studying failure of a lamp demands the observation of a set of lamps). 
Should I do the following?

initial time until first failure time= observation 1
time from 'fixed-first-failure' until second failure = observation 2
and so on

Or should I split in causes of  failure and do the same thing above to each cause?

Comment: This sounds like a competing risks problem, when one unit is at risk for more types of failure. There is quite a lot of literature online, maybe that is the type of model that you need

Comment: I found that I can work on it as survival data but since It hasn't censoring and I can't really use K-M I could consider S(x) = 1 - Fn(x). where Fn(x) is the cumative empirical function of risk (or something like that, sorry about my english). So I would use the risk function (doesn't need censoring) to estimate the survival function ( which depends on the censoring). There's actually a video in youtube about that, unfortunatelly it's just an overall explanation.

Comment: And there is another thing very important. My data observes only one item. recording the work of that item until it fails or brake for some reason, then there's the maintenance (observation 1). The item gets "new" again, thanks to maintenance, and start working again then it fails one second time (observation 2) and it goes on. the teacher who is helping me told me I can't treat this data as a proper survival data because there is dependence between the observation. Though I'm really convinced It's possible I couldn't find literature to convince him and I'd really appreciate some help to do so